# displaying an 19-digit integer

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am currently working with an SQlite database.

Picture shown is the screenshot of my created table using the SQlite manager in Firefox.

---

[image]

---

I wanted to save 3765627420983441154 but in the table it is saved as 3765627420983441400.

What do I need to do, so that the correct value is saved?

Comment: I don't see a picture? Please share your code.

Comment: I can't post a picture since my current reputation is below 10.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: in sqlite manager, you can easily create a table without having to code it.

Comment: in the answer list. Thanks

Comment: How are you storing the value in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite can store integers as signed 64-bit numbers, i.e., up to 9223372036854775807.

SQLite Manager is not able to display such large numbers because JavaScript does not have 64-bit integers. (This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/issues/detail?id=3).)
However, in your actual database, these values work just fine.

Please note that if you do not want to do computations on this value, you should not try to store `empID` as a number.

Comment: yeah. What I am trying to do only in my empID is just a checking whenever I receive a value.
It is really working when I try to check if that value is in my database, it returns a value testifying that it is.
I am just trying to seek an answer why it is displaying like that. :D Thanks